# Editing properties of objects individually and need "edit" boxes to open dynamically for each property

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The backend is Python with Django Models. Below is what I have in the User Inteface.[image: UI to display object properties]

When the user clicks the "edit" pen I want a textbox input to show up right beneath the previous value, also a "submit changes" button pops up at the top of the page. The user needs to be able to edit as many properties as desired and then submit all changes at once. My object has over 75 properties so the javascript will get really long and cumbersome if I create a unique function for each property. So far I have this:

html:

```
<button id="edit_submit" type="submit" form="job_text_edit">Commit Changes</button>

<form id="job_text_edit" action="pass to backend"></form>
<table class="z-depth-3">
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 200px">Job Name:</td>
  <td>
     {{job.job_name}}<a href="#"><i class="tiny material-icons" onclick="jobEdit()">edit</i></a>
     <input id="job_name_i" name="job_name_i" type="text" form="job_text_edit">
  </td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr>
   <td>Work Schedule:</td>
   <td> 
    {{job.work_schedule}}<a><i class="tiny material-icons" onclick="jobEdit()">edit</i></a>
    <input id="work_schedule_i" name="work_schedule_i" type="text" form="job_text_edit"> 
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#edit_submit').hide();
    $('#job_name_i').hide();
    $('#work_schedule_i').hide();
  })
  function jobEdit(){
    $('#edit_submit').show();
    $('#job_name_i').show();
    $('#work_schedule_i').show();
    
  }
</script>
```

The problem is that when you click any "edit" pens, all the edit boxes will pop up. Is there a way to let the function know which one was clicked so I can implement conditional statements in the function to show only the necessary boxes? I tried passing in a string with the input id but the function throws errors when given string arguments. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you pull data from the back end, you need to pull through an id or some unique value also.

This value would be unique to each indiviudal row you show in your screenshot above, or an element in that row.

Then when you render your html, append the id (unique value) to the end of the current id (html id on the element)

So for example, where you have input id="job_name_i", you can add (append) the unique value (id) to the end of it upon rendering.

You can then, instead of passing through your function call in the onclick (and defining the onClick in the html), you can set up an event listener in the init part of your javascript like so:

```
$("[id^=job_name_i]").on('click', event => {
  const clickedElement = $(event.target);
});
```

The above will listen for a click on any element that begins with
job_name_i (remember your unique value will be appended to the end of it.

So the above would go inside the below block.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

You now have access to the specific clicked element on the page, to do as you need, adding stuff below or above it. So you can access the ID with by using event.target.id and you can pass that in to your function.

Something like the following.

```
  function jobEdit(id){
    $(id).show(); 
    // OR
    $(someelement + id).show(); 
  }
```

Comment: Excellent idea and thanks for the response! I am running into a snag. The "edit" pen icon is a different element from the input, so I can append the property value to the id of the input but then it won't be picked up by the event listener because the input element is hidden; alternatively I can append the value to the id of the "edit" element but then I pull in that element and manipulation of that simply hides or shows the pen! How could I click the pen element to access the input element?

Comment: Hey, no worries. So your pen element will have it's own unique id. Which can be selected by the event listener. 

Then in the event listener function, to access that specific pen elements input, you can get it with the following: 

$("specificPenElementID").siblings("input"). The .siblings part gets all elements in the same level of hierarchy as your edit button (which is within your td tag). Then the "input" part narrows it to be the element that is an input only.

Comment: I cannot seem to get the "sibling" to work. It is The only examples I saw online identified the target element by class and then retrieved the siblings so I'm suspicious it might not be picking up the element by "id". This js tries to log the siblings but it shows up empty in the log: `$("[id^=text_edit]").on('click', event => {
    var clickedElement = $(event.target);
    var edit_input=$(clickedElement).siblings()
    console.log(edit_input)`

Comment: I achieved a solution to this. `
    var edit_input=$(clickedElement).parent().next();` got me the input field. The only negative being that the input now has to be the next element or it won't work.

Comment: Nice! There are definitely cleaner ways around it. Investigate with .find and appending unique ID values to thinks and finding elements based on that. The trick is really getting the beginning of the ID the same for all elements, then when rendering, appending the unique ID to it, that way you can find things easily without elements being next to each other necessarily. eg.

$(sectionElement).find("#whateverIDStartsWith" + uniqueID);